chatbot server with llamaindex and FastAPI
I am trying to make a chatbot server (RAG system) with llamaindex and FastApi.
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex, StorageContext, SimpleDirectoryReader, load_index_from_storage
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface_api import HuggingFaceInferenceAPIEmbedding

from llama_index.llms.groq import Groq
from llama_index.core import Settings
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Question(BaseModel):
    question: str

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=["*"],
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

load_dotenv()
Settings.llm = Groq(temperature=0.8,model="llama-3.1-70b-versatile", api_key=os.getenv('GROQ_API_KEY'))
Settings.embed_model = HuggingFaceInferenceAPIEmbedding(model_name="OrdalieTech/Solon-embeddings-large-0.1", token = os.getenv('HF_API_KEY'))

try:
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir = './storage')
    res_index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)
    index_loaded = True
except:
    index_loaded = False

if not index_loaded:
    print('index creation, please wait...')
    res_doc = SimpleDirectoryReader('./documents').load_data()
    res_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(res_doc)
    res_index.storage_context.persist(persist_dir = './storage')
    print('index creation completed')

chat_engine = res_index.as_chat_engine(
    chat_mode="context",
    system_prompt = (...)
)

@app.post('/ask')
def ask(question : Question):
    response = chat_engine.chat(question.question)
    return {"response":response.response}

My problem is simple: when several people connect at the same time to my server, they all share the same chat history. For example, if user A writes "I am David", and right after user B asks "what is my name?", the chatbot will answer "You are David".
I would like each user to have their own chat history (I don't know if the problem should be solved at the llamaindex or FastApi level)
Thanks in advance for your help
